# Three js RectAreaLight on MeshPhongMaterial no light reflection (OES_texture_half_float not supported)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, webgl

I want to add RectAreaLight to a three.js scene where I placed object with MeshPhongMaterial however there is no light reflection on the objects.
I found a working example here:
[Link](http://groovemechanic.net/three.js.halffloat/examples/webgl_lights_rectarealight.html)

You can see the source code when you open the developer tools.

So I tried to port it to React and the scene renders all objects but there is light reflection.
In line 46 the OES_texture_half_float error was thrown. I commented this lines out. Maybe it has something to do with this.

Here is the not working codesandbox:
[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-water-zv97y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of  issues in your code:

- You have to import `RectAreaLightUniformsLib` and call its `init()` method.
- As mentioned in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?#api/en/lights/RectAreaLight), `RectAreaLight` only supports PBR materials (meaning `MeshStandardMaterial` and `MeshPhysicalMaterial`).
- There is also no shadow support yet so setting flags like `castShadow` and `receiveShadow` won't have any effect.

Fixed codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-cherry-4jh72

Comment: thank you it works fine :) Just wondering the first example use MeshPhongMaterial

Comment: The mentioned example uses `79dev`. At that time, `MeshPhongMaterial` was supported (however the implementation was incorrect since the implementation of `RectAreaLight` is not compatible to a phong material).